# Windows account locked out when scheduled task updated or run

Tags: windows-server-2012, scheduled-task

On my Windows Server 2012 Standard instance, whenever I modify or run a scheduled task, it locks out the user account that runs the scheduled task. I've tried changing the user account and it doesn't make any difference, the next time the scheduled task is run or modified the new user account is locked too. This started happening a few weeks ago when I installed windows updates. Here is the error displayed when trying to modify the scheduled task with an account that is not locked out:

[image]

Googling this issue brings up [this bug](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2548120/account-is-incorrectly-locked-after-you-create-or-change-multiple-sche), which has a hotfix available, however it's not for Windows Server 2012. I tried installing it anyway, and it errors.

[image]

At this point I'm not sure how to resolve this issue. I have the latest window updates installed. Because the user account keeps getting locked out, I can't consistently run my scheduled tasks, which is affecting my application. Any ideas?